# limit with GIF and FPF

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

In this I could not understand how they got te value of a,b and $\lambda$.

Can anybody please explain me .

Comment: Excellent question. What trouble are you facing understanding the solution?

Comment: @navinstudent I think at x=0 the value is zero . So b should be equal to zero . But they how to find a and $\lambda$

Comment: For x<0 the numerator has   $\{K^2+K+e^x-1\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that they have written the statement: "Function is diffrentiable in R"

This simply means $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=f(0)$$
$$1=b=\lambda$$
This was by applying continuity.

By applying differentiation rules across $x=0$ we get:
$$a=e^0=1$$ 
Thus $$a+b+\lambda=3$$

Comment: How you got b=1

Comment: @Koolman $b=e^0$. It's a JEE question, Isn't it? I seem to have crossed path with this question lately

Comment: For x<0 the numerator will be less than 1

Comment: I think b= {e$^{0-h}$}where h is very small number

Comment: No. Actually your question has a misprint if you cared to notice. In that case, Numerator should be :$\{K^2+K+e^x-1\}$

Comment: Yes it is a jee question

Comment: Yes for x<0 the numerator has $\{K^2+K+e^x-1\}$ .It would be misprint

Comment: No. $K^2+K-1$ will always be a positive integer. in that case, it's fractional part should be 0. Then only considerable thing which will be left is $e^x$ which indeed, is less than 0 but when $x<0$, $\{x\}=x+1$ By that logic, solution given is correct.@Koolman

Comment: At x =0 $e^0 =1 $ whose fractional part is zero . so limit is zero and b=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57805/discussion-between-thedeadlegend-and-koolman).